# Cannot get simple external script to load with Locker Service active

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I cannot seem to get a component to load even a basic static resource script when Locker Service is active in a Winter preview sandbox. It works fine if Locker Service is deactivated. Otherwise, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

> Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$LockerTestComp$controller$doInit [lockerTest is not defined] Failing descriptor: {c$LockerTestComp$controller$doInit}. Please try again.

**LockerTest.vfp**

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $Lightning.use("c:LockerTestApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent('c:LockerTestComp', {}, "lightning", function(cmp) { });
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**LockerTestApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" >
</aura:application>
```

**LockerTestComp.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.LockerTest}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
    Hello World
</aura:component>
```

**LockerTestCompController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        lockerTest();
    }
})
```

**LockerTest.js** (static resource)

```
var lockerTest = function() {
    alert('it worked');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var lockerTest=` is not creating a global method - its a local variable not in the scope of the doInit method. Strict mode removes the creation of automatic globals and you simply need to indicate your intent is to actually create a globally visible function using `window.lockertest=`

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode for more details on strict mode and global variables.